# How to get user's email address using facebook unique number?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Initially, we have enabled FB login to one of our iOS app. At that time, we were only storing Facebook unique number in our database for user's unique identification purpose. Now that our customer is asking us to enable Google Login, since we didn't store user's email address at the time of their login, it became tricky for us authenticate existing FB users if at all if they want to use Google login. Consider, user is using google email as their FB login. Now we need your help in getting user's email id by using FB unique number which we already have it in our db. Your help in this regard would be highly appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the email of a user on Facebook, unless he specifically authorized your App with the `email` permission.

Comment: Sure, we are taking consent from the user and all of them have authorized the app to access their facebook account. After that only, we were able to get their FB unique number. However, at that time, we didn't get their email id. Now, is there a way to get email by using their FB unique number?

Comment: no, of course not. that would make the email permission pointless. you have to re-authorize them with the email permission.